# Codeigniter database Join on two columns based on multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pyrocms

I want to help in following query:-

```
    $this->db->select('nbr.*, dm.dma, st.abbrev as state,unit.size_title as ad_size_title,unit_u.size_title as ad_unit_title,di.size_title as ad_di_title,color.title as color_title');
$this->db->from('default_new_buy_request as nbr');
$this->db->join('default_dmadata as dm', 'nbr.dma_id = dm.id', 'left');
$this->db->join('default_states as st', 'nbr.state_id = st.id', 'left');
```

The `nbr.dma_id` comes with multiple comma (',') separated values and is going to compared with all `dm.id` in `default_dmadata`, but here it just compare only one value with `dm.id`.
In short I need a an explode() type functionality to compare each of value with second column.

Comment: shall I give the mysql? could u convert it Codeigniter??

Comment: Well, i just convert this query into codeigniter function, but still did't get the required output, as i mentioned before, the values that consisting the column dm.da_id are like this (1,3,6).But it shows an sql error to to mismatch query structure.But i am sure i have coded every thing on proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try it?

Use If the values In comma

In MYSQL, try it with Codeigniter

```
LEFT JOIN default_dmadata dm ON FIND_IN_SET(dm.dma_id, dm.id)
```

Comment: This is my codeigniter active record style query, $this->db->join('default_dmadata as dm', 'FIND_IN_SET(nbr.dma_id , dm.id)', 'left');